# Cannot use all cores on Honor5C (Android 6.0)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, operating-system

I am working on a rooted Honor5C phone in order to benchmark some computer vision algorithms. The basic idea is to see the phone as a all-in-one well optimized embedded board giving you all you might need in an IoT context (wifi, lte, camera, storage, performance...).

For those who might not know, the Honor5C has two ARM Cortex-A53 quad cores running at different speed. When reading the net, it seems one group is used for performance and the other one for battery saving.

During the different benchmarks I tried to do on the phone, it seems I couldn't get all the cores running for my application, basically a C++ binary. So I've tried running a simple script and check with `top` the core usage. Here is the script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
i=0
while : ; do
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

When executing 8 of this script, only 50% of the CPU maximum usage is used letting me think only 4 out of the 8 cores of the phone are used for this.  Does the OS limit their use ? Is there any solution to force the use of the available cores ? Has anyone encountered this issue ?

Comment: How are you sure that 1 physical core has to correspond to 1 application/thread? Also, use [PerfMon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.perfmon) for accurate-to-core usage stats.

Comment: I come from the computing field, I'm not an Android expert at all. You might ask why we use a phone and not other boards but as I said, it's a great all-in-one board. That said, I am optimizing a C++ library that I want to run on the phone and bench it. I am using Neon and OpenMP to optimize everything. And OpenMP tells me he can see 8 cores. And usually with OpenMP the best performances is when 1 thread = 1 core. But with a C binary or this script the maximum usage I can have is 50%.

Comment: Well I'm no expert either (that's why I'm not posting an answer), but still I recommend using that app to confirm your observations at least.